# OpenOffice bug while exporting from Calc using xslt filters

Tags: xslt, export, openoffice-calc

I have a row-based data in Calc which I want to export to xml using xslt filters. The filters work properly except when values in two adjacent columns are the same. For example, see the data below ...

```
SrNo      Col2      Col3      Col4      Col5
1         PQR       123       567       LMN
2         OPQ       665       786       BCD
3         EUR       443       443       UFF
4         OLE       345       887       JAS
5         EJR       565       565       OEP
```

For the above data, this error occurs only for lines 3 and 5. For some reason, the filter skips col4 and takes the value from col5. For rest of the data the export works perfectly fine. Here is the xslt code ...

```
<row>
<col1><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[1]"/></col1>
<col2><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[2]"/></col2>
<col3><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[3]"/></col3>
<col4><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[4]"/></col4>
<col5><xsl:value-of select="table:table-cell[5]"/></col5>
</row>
```

Can someone please give any inputs on this ? It's pretty weird and I am badly stuck up due to this. Btw, I am using OpenOffice 3.1.1 (Build 9420) with xslt 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

That was great code Rohit; it definitely helped send me in the right direction. I was having a hard time getting the XSLT 2.0 code working in my LibreOffice installation, so I converted the code to use XSLT 1.0 (named templates instead of functions calls, and an extension to be able to pass a node into the recursive function). In case someone needs it, my code is below. Note that it is not general purpose code - you will need to replace my fields with your own.

This particular example exports a spreadsheet into a valid .plist file that is recognized by XCode. It has been tested with LibreOffice 3.5 running on Vista.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
    xmlns:xt="http://www.jclark.com/xt"
    extension-element-prefixes="xt"
    xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
    xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="office table text">

    <!--xsl:output method = "xml" indent = "yes" encoding = "UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration = "no"/-->
    <xsl:output method = "xml" indent = "yes" encoding = "UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration = "no" doctype-system = "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd" doctype-public = "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" />

    <xsl:template name="getColumnValue">
        <xsl:param name="tableRow"/>
        <xsl:param name="colIndex"/>
        <xsl:param name="currentIndex"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$currentIndex &lt; $colIndex">
                <xsl:variable name="repeatColumns" select="xt:node-set($tableRow)/table:table-cell[$currentIndex]/@table:number-columns-repeated"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$repeatColumns">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$currentIndex + $repeatColumns - 1 &gt;= $colIndex">
                                <xsl:value-of select="xt:node-set($tableRow)/table:table-cell[$currentIndex]"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:variable name = "recursiveResult">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="$tableRow"/>
                                        <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="$colIndex - $repeatColumns + 1"/>
                                        <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="$currentIndex + 1"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$recursiveResult"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:variable name = "recursiveResult">
                            <xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue">
                                <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="$tableRow"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="$colIndex"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="$currentIndex + 1"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$recursiveResult"/>

                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="xt:node-set($tableRow)/table:table-cell[$colIndex]"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- By setting the PropertyValue "URL" in the properties used in storeToURL(), -->
    <!-- we can pass a single parameter to this stylesheet.                         -->
    <!-- Caveat: If we use the "URL" property in the stylesheet and call in OOo     -->
    <!-- from the menu "File" > "Export...", OOo assigns a target URL. And that     -->
    <!-- might not be what we want.                                                 -->
    <xsl:param name="targetURL"/>

    <xsl:variable name="exportDate">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(substring-before($targetURL,';'))=10">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($targetURL,';')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($targetURL)=10">
                <xsl:value-of select="$targetURL"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="exportUser">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(substring-after($targetURL,';'))>0">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($targetURL,';')"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <plist version="1.0">
            <dict>
                <key>Animations</key>
                <array>
                    <!-- Process all tables -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//table:table"/>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="table:table">
        <!-- Process all table-rows after the column labels in table-row 1 -->
        <xsl:for-each select="table:table-row">
            <xsl:if test="position()>1">
                <dict>
                    <key>character</key>
                    <string>
                        <xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue"> <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="1"/> <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="1"/> <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="."/> </xsl:call-template>
                    </string>

                    <key>animation</key>
                    <string>
                        <xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue"> <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="2"/> <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="1"/> <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="."/> </xsl:call-template>
                    </string>

                    <key>cycle</key>
                    <xsl:variable name="cycleTmp">
                        <xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue"> <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="3"/> <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="1"/> <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="."/> </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:if test="$cycleTmp > 0">
                        <true/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="$cycleTmp = 0">
                        <false/>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <key>frames</key>
                    <integer>
                        <xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue"> <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="4"/> <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="1"/> <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="."/> </xsl:call-template>
                    </integer>

                    <key>randomSpeedPercent</key>
                    <integer>
                        <xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue"> <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="5"/> <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="1"/> <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="."/> </xsl:call-template>
                    </integer>

                    <key>spriteNameRoot</key>
                    <string>
                        <xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue"> <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="6"/> <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="1"/> <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="."/> </xsl:call-template>
                    </string>

                    <key>spriteSheetName</key>
                    <string>
                        <xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue"> <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="7"/> <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="1"/> <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="."/> </xsl:call-template>
                    </string>

                    <key>anchorX</key>
                    <integer>
                        <xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue"> <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="11"/> <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="1"/> <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="."/> </xsl:call-template>
                    </integer>

                    <key>anchorY</key>
                    <integer>
                        <xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue"> <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="12"/> <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="1"/> <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="."/> </xsl:call-template>
                    </integer>

                </dict>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. Will also help if you can vote up my answer if it was useful :)

Comment: Wow. I lost a whole night finding this problem and looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to number-columns-repeated attribute to table:table-cell element in the sheet's underlying data structure. For more details, please refer to http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=29674 and http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=11865.

Though the latter link claims to have resolved the issue, the solution is not quite what I was looking for. I required a simple index-based solution which allows a more flexible xml generation. Here is what I tried to work out.

I have used xslt 2.0 to make use of user defined functions. Here is the stylesheet ...

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

<xsl:function name="my:getColumnValue">
    <xsl:param name="tableRow" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:param name="colIndex"/>
    <xsl:param name="currentIndex"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$currentIndex &lt; $colIndex">
            <xsl:variable name="repeatColumns" select="$tableRow/table:table-cell[$currentIndex]/@table:number-columns-repeated"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$repeatColumns">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$currentIndex + $repeatColumns - 1 &gt;= $colIndex"><xsl:value-of select="$tableRow/table:table-cell[$currentIndex]"/></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="my:getColumnValue($tableRow, $colIndex - $repeatColumns + 1, $currentIndex + 1)"/></xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="my:getColumnValue($tableRow, $colIndex, $currentIndex + 1)"/></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$tableRow/table:table-cell[$colIndex]"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="//table:table">
    <Tests>
        <!-- Process all table rows -->
        <xsl:variable name="colCount" select="count(table:table-row[1]/table:table-cell)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="table:table-row">
            <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <Test>
                <SrNo><xsl:value-of select="my:getColumnValue(.,1,1)"/></SrNo>
                <Name><xsl:value-of select="my:getColumnValue(.,2,1)"/></Name>
                <Age><xsl:value-of select="my:getColumnValue(.,3,1)"/></Age>
                <Height><xsl:value-of select="my:getColumnValue(.,4,1)"/></Height>
                <Address><xsl:value-of select="my:getColumnValue(.,5,1)"/></Address>
            </Test>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Tests>
</xsl:template>
```

The tags used above are just placeholders. Please replace them with appropriate ones in your xslt. This solution is limited by number of recursive calls allowed by the xslt processor.

If xslt 1.0 supports sending node as params, then we can try to replace the above udf to get a template based solution. If you find any bugs, do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Marcel's solution looks complicated, but works perfect and is not so complicated to adapt.

So, again in short for everybody: 
You basically copy&paste the whole template into your xsl:

```
<xsl:template name="getColumnValue"> ... </>
```

Then, replace all the standard table:row (which is failing) with

```
<xsl:call-template name="getColumnValue"> 
    <xsl:with-param name="colIndex" select="1"/> 
    <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="1"/> 
    <xsl:with-param name="tableRow" select="."/> 
</xsl:call-template>
```

Be sure to adjust the "colIndex" values, but leave the currentIndex on 1!
Finally, add the xt lines of the header to yours.

```
xmlns:xt="http://www.jclark.com/xt"
extension-element-prefixes="xt"
```

Perfect, Marcel!